# Runtime error in IE 6

Tags: javascript

I am getting runtime error in IE 6 for below code.

```
function loadFromPopup(url) {
 if (top.opener){
     top.opener.window.location.href = url;
     window.close();
     return false;
 }
 return true;
}
```

Really appreciate if any one can give some suggestions.

Comment: Where do "top" come from? Maybe you can give us a bit more code so we can understand.

Comment: what if you get rid of `window.` ?

Answer (score 1):

`top` is a global variable that refers to the top-level window containing the current frame (possibly within more framesets, each of whose containing window object can be obtained recursively using each window's `parent` property). `opener` refers to the window that opened the current window using `window.open()`.

If your document isn't within a frame, just drop the `top` and use `window.opener` or just `opener`. `opener` is already a reference to the window you want, so no need for the `window` that follows it, though I wouldn't expect it to do any harm: a `window` object has a property called `window` that refers to itself. Also, you should check whether the opener window has been closed before doing anything to it using its `closed` property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but doesn't `opener` refer to the window? Try:

```
 top.opener.location.href = url;
```

Edit: What are you trying to close with `window.close`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't develop for IE6.  You will spend hours and hours frustrated.

IE6 is very old.  Encourage your users to update their browser.

http://ie6update.com/

Comment: -1. Not wanting to develop for IE 6 isn't going to make it go away.